# Is there a way to expire FriendlyId slugs after a certain time?

Tags: friendly-id

I'd like to give my users the ability to change their slugs and have their old slugs redirect.

But after some time, I'd like to have the old slugs become available.

Is there an official or recommended way to do this?

I suppose it's as simple as running a nightly job which deletes records older than X days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a great idea to do that because URL's stop being URL's anymore if you do that.

However a solution would be to go through FriendlyId history table every day and remove records which are older that given threshold.